# Retrofit post request null body

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to post my data in json format. I think I'm doing it right, but it's making the mistake: 
body = null, response code =417

Json data needs to post in the following format:

```
{
    "Users": [{
            'Phone': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Name': 'yyyyy'
        }
    ]
}
```

My code is all:

```
@POST("api")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<TRList> savePost(@Field("Phone") String Phone,
                      @Field("Name") String Name);
}


}

public class UsersList {
@SerializedName("Users")
@Expose
private List<Post> users = null;
public List<Post> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
public void setTr(List<Post> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}

public class Post {
@SerializedName("Phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("AS")
@Expose
private String Name;
//getter and setter methods
}

public void sendPost(Post post){
    mAPIService.savePost(post.getPhone().toString(),post.getName().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<UsersList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UsersList> call, Response<UsersList> response) {
            Log.d("requestError", "onResponse: "+ call.request().body().toString());
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code

First create Output class

**Create class `User`**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

@SerializedName("Phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getPhone() {
return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
```

**Create class `UserList`**

```
public class UserList {

 @SerializedName("Users")
 @Expose
 private List<User> users = null;

 public List<User> getUsers() {
   return users;
 }

 public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
   this.users = users;
 }

}
```

for input class you already have post class

```
public class Post {
@SerializedName("Phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("AS")
@Expose
private String Name;
//getter and setter methods
}
```

**on your interface create this method**

```
@POST("api")
Call<UserList> savePost(@@Body Post post);
```

call service

```
public void sendPost(Post post){
 mAPIService.savePost(post).enqueue(new Callback<UserList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserList> call, Response<UserList> response) {
            Log.d("requestError", "onResponse: "+ call.request().body().toString());
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                showResponse(response.body().toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I did it the way you said, but my APIService.class file shouldn't be like this:
    @POST("api")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<TRList> savePost(@Field("Phone") String Phone,
                          @Field("Tlf") String Tlf);

Comment: Yes , it should be like this @POST("api")
Call<UserList> savePost(@@Body Post post);

Comment: application is crashed

Comment: can I have  your base URL , so I can test it my self

Comment: {
    "Users": [{
            'Phone': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Name': 'yyyyy'
        }
    ]
}

can you give me what code will work like this? Please. I'm in a very difficult situation.

Comment: this is you request { "Users": [{ 'Phone': 'xxxxxxxxxxx', 'Name': 'yyyyy' } ] }  or response? if request then share response please.

Comment: for fast support you can contact me on my skype emad.abdelmonem

Comment: pro.emad@gmail.com

Comment: Can you please help?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60483567/how-to-know-server-accepted-date-format